# This does not seem to be an official Ubuntu Package. Please retry after updating the indexes of available packages

Tags: apt, crash, lts

From time to time all kind of applications (like Upwork, Visual Code) running on Ubuntu crashing suddenly. When I open the report tool that pops up and look for the specific error which caused the crash I am getting this error:

> This does not seem to be an official Ubuntu Package. Please retry
> after updating the indexes of available packages.

OS version is: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: That's true. Neither of these are in the official Ubuntu repositories. You either installed the snap package or the .deb package provided by the developers of these software. File a bug at their appropriate bug tracker.